# Does this function belong to $L^2(\mathbb{D})$?

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, sobolev-spaces

**Edit:** After the  answer  of  Prof. Eremenko to the  previous  version, I realized that  a  weaker  assumption works  for  the  main motivation of this post.  so  I  revise the  question.

The  unit  disk in the  plane  is denoted by $\mathbb{D}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2 <1\}$

Assume that  $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{R}$  is  a smooth (or real  analytic  function)  such that for  every  analytic   curve $\alpha \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ , $f$ is  uniformly continuous  on $\alpha \cap \mathbb{D}$.

> Does  this  imply that  $f\in L^2(\mathbb{D})$, or at  least  $f\in L^p(\mathbb{D})$for  some  $p >1$?

**Motivations:**

I  encountered such type  of  functions in the "proof"  of  the  proposition of  the  following  note:

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408037

In reality, the  proof  is  not  correct, because  the  above  assumption does  not  imply that  $f$  has  a  (unique)  continuous  extension  to the  boundary.  The  mistake  of the  note was  that it  assumed  such  continuous  extension.

More  precisely we  have  a  vector  field $X=P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$  on the  plane.
We define a  linear  operator  on the  space  of  smooth  functions  on the  plane  with $L_X(f)=X.f=Pf_x+Qf_y$.
We  wish  to  solve  the  differential equation $$X.f=g$$.(This  equation is  called "Homological equation" in the  following  talk: "https://cms.math.ca/Events/Toulouse2004/abs/ss7.html#lt")

If $\gamma$ is  a  hyperbolic limit  cycle  of  $X$ with period $T$  and  surrounds  a  hyperbolic  singularity, we  can solve the above  equation in the  interior  of  $\gamma$ provided $\int_0^T g(\gamma(t))dt=0$. However   we  wish  to  pass  from  the  interior  of $\gamma$ to  its  exterior.

The  true  fact  is  that, in the  interior  of  $\gamma$, the  solution  $f$  of  $X.f=g$  satisfies  the  above  **Assumption**.  (In this  post ,  for  simplicity, we  replace  an  arbitrary  $\gamma$ by  the  unit  circle)   So  the  question in this post would  be  a  motivation to  consider a  Sobolov  space  for  action of  $L_X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. Take a curve tangent to $S$ from inside, for example an arc of a circle. Then take a narrow neighborhood $V$ of this curve. Then there exists a function, $C^\infty$ in the open disk, zero outside $V$ and growing as much as you want in $V$, so it does not belong to any $L^p$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please give a comment on  the following revised version of the assumption: for every analytic curve $\alpha$, f is uniform continuous on $\alpha \cap \mathbb{D}$. This new version work for the same motivation in my question.Moreover is there an example of real analytic f of your example?

Comment: In my example, $f$ can be real analytic, in fact of the form $|g(z)|$ with $g$ complex analytic. If you want to modify your question, modify it in the text of the question, not in the comment.